# How to create html element <li> tag inside <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have li and input inside my ul tag and I want to generate and create my own html tag in javascript. So far here is what I've got from my default html view:

```
<ul id="my_list" class="ks-cboxtags" style="margin-left:80px; margin-top:-20px">
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxOne"><label for="checkboxOne">valA</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxTwo"><label for="checkboxTwo">valB</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThree"><label for="checkboxThree">valC</label></li>                                   
</ul>
```

my point of view or pseudo code is something like this:

```
temp_list = ["ValA","ValB","ValC"];

$.each(temp_list, function (i, item) {
  console.log(item.proc_area); //-- need dynamic html tag here to be passed inside the ul tag                    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [**`append()`**](https://api.jquery.com/append/) the element (*li*) in each iteration with the current *item*.

**Demo:**

```js
var temp_list = ["ValA","ValB","ValC"];
$.each(temp_list, function (i, item) {
  $('#my_list').append($('<li>').html(`<label>${item}</label>`));               
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="my_list" class="ks-cboxtags" style="margin-left:80px;"></ul>
```

Comment: looks good to me but i need the full li,inpu and label tag just like from this reference and just want to be dynamic value came from javascript. https://codepen.io/quinlo/pen/ReMRXz

Comment: oh looks like I need to pass .html extension rather than .text

Comment: @Rockn'Roll, if the string is htmlString then you have to use `html()` ....

Answer (score 0):

```js
var template = `<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_{{counter}}"><label for="checkbox_{{counter}}">{{label}}</label>`;

var temp_list = ["ValA", "ValB", "ValC"];

$.each(temp_list, function(i, item) {

  var values = {
    counter: i,
    label: item
  };
  
  var parsedTemplate = template.replace(/{{(\w+)}}/g, function(_,k){ return values[k]; });
  $('#my_list').append($(`<li>${parsedTemplate}</li>`));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="my_list" class="ks-cboxtags" style="margin-left:80px;"></ul>
```